# Dynamically writing to text file based on received dictionary information

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, file-writing

I am trying to write jobs to a text file based on dictionary information. The dictionary information is received from the server and is not always the same. It contains `file_count` and `file_paths` which the `file_paths` is a list. e.g,

```
{'file_paths': ['/file/path/one', '/file/path/two'], 'file_count': 2}
```

I have a baseline to write out a block of text which contains variables that would be inserted based on the dictionary's information. e.g,

```
text_baseline = ('This is the %s file\n'
                'and the file path is\n'
                'path: %s\n')
```

This baseline would need to be **duplicated** based on the number of files received from the dictionary and written into a text file.

So, for example, if the dictionary has three files it would have three blocks of text each with updated information of file number and paths.

I know that I have to do something like this:

```
f = open("myfile.txt", "w")
for i in dict.get("file_count"):
    f.write(text_baseline)     # this needs to write in the paths and the file numbers
```

I am having a hard time figuring out how to update the paths and file numbers based on the info received using the baseline.

Comment: What output do you expect to see for the input shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use str.format() to format the string.

```
data = {'file_paths': ['/file/path/one', '/file/path/two'], 'file_count': 2} 
text_baseline = "this is the {}th file and the path is {}"
with open('path','w') as f:
    for i in range(int(dict.get('file_count'))):
         f.write(text_baseline.format(i,data['file_paths']))
```

Comment: I'm using python3.4 is string format supported in that version?

Comment: it is supported

Comment: You're missing some close parens

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did miss the ones at the end. thank you.

Comment: Still coming up short

Comment: I dont get why exactly this matters. I am showing him a concept, not telling him to copy and paste this.

Answer (score 1):

Can use enumerate and string format here:

```
paths = {'file_paths': ['/file/path/one', '/file/path/two'], 'file_count': 2}
text_baseline = ('''This is the {num} file
and the file path is
path: {path}
''')
with open('myfile.txt','w') as f:
    for i, path in enumerate(paths['file_paths'], 1):
        f.write(text_baseline.format(num=i, path=path))
```

Comment: I'm using python3.4 is string format supported in that version?